# Is there any difference between using "ifvarclass => 'class'" or "class::" notation when adding promises?

Tags: cfengine

Is there any difference in the way the `ifvarclass => 'class'` construct vs `class::` construct work? Can I use both interchangeably?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly, but almost. Note that any time you use a class expression
(`expression::`) that context restriction applies until the next expression or
until the next promise type so it may apply to more than one promise at a time
where ifvarclass applies only to one promise at a time. Also since 3.7.0 there
is an [`if` alias](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.10/reference-promise-types.html#if) to `ifvarclass` which is nicer to type IMHO.

For simple class based constraints yes, they can be used interchangeably.

```
bundle agent main
{
  vars:
    "classes" slist => { "linux", "windows" };

  reports:

    "I am a Linux box"
      ifvarclass => "linux";

    linux::
      "I am still a Linux box";
}

R: I am a Linux box
R: I am still a Linux box
```

You can also use simple expressions interchangeably.

```
bundle agent main
{
  vars:
    "classes" slist => { "linux", "windows" };

  reports:

    "I am a Linux box"
      ifvarclass => "linux.64_bit";

    linux.64_bit::
      "I am still a Linux box";
}

R: I am a Linux box
R: I am still a Linux box
```

Until 3.7.0 you could not use variables in traditional context class expressions
(`$(my_variable)::`) and `ifvarclass` was useful for being able to use a
canonified variable as a constraint.

For example until 3.7 you had to do this:

```
bundle agent main
{
  vars:
    "classes" slist => { "linux", "windows" };

  reports:

    "I am $(classes) box"
      ifvarclass => "$(classes)";
}

R: I am linux box
```

As of 3.7 you can use [variable class expressions](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.10/reference-language-concepts-classes.html#making-decisions-based-on-classes):

```
bundle agent main
{
  vars:
    "classes" slist => { "linux", "windows" };

  reports:

    "$(classes)"::
      "I am $(classes) box";
}

R: I am linux box
```

That works fine until the list of things your checking contains characters that
are not valid in classes (like dashes). This is where `ifvarclass` is most
useful as it allows you to transform a string on the fly or even use a function
that returns boolean like [`isvariable()`](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.10/reference-functions-isvariable.html).

Here is an example showing `ifvarclass` in use with [`canonify()`](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.10/reference-functions-canonify.html).

```
bundle agent main
{
  classes:
    # A class that was derived from a string containing invalid characters like special-class
    "special_class" expression => "any";

  vars:
    "classes" slist => { "linux", "windows", "special-class" };

  reports:

    "I am $(classes) box"
      ifvarclass => canonify( $(classes) );
}

R: I am linux box
R: I am special-class box
```